# change gradle Dockerfile to be executed as root user

Tags: docker, gradle, gitlab, dockerfile

I am working in gitlab and want to use gradle to build my java project, but I ran into this bug with gitlab runner: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/issues/2570

One comment is: I can confirm that it works in  v9.1.3 but v9.2.0 is broken. Only when I use root user inside container I can proceed. That really should be fixed, because that this regression is seriously impacting security.

So my question is on which places I have to change the Dockerfile to execute as root user? https://github.com/keeganwitt/docker-gradle/blob/b0419babd3271f6c8e554fbc8bbd8dc909936763/jdk8-alpine/Dockerfile

So my idea is to change the dockerfile that it is executed as root push it to my registry and use it inside gitlab. But I am not so much into linux/docker that I know where the user is defined in the file. Maybe I am totally wrong?

```
build_java:
  image: gradle:4.4.1-jdk8-alpine-root
  stage: build_java
  script:
    - gradle build
  artifacts:
    expire_in: 1 hour # Workaround to delete artifacts after build, we only artifacts it to keep it between stages (but not after the build)
    paths:
    - build/
    - .gradle/
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine

CMD ["gradle"]

ENV GRADLE_HOME /opt/gradle
ENV GRADLE_VERSION 4.4.1

ARG GRADLE_DOWNLOAD_SHA256=e7cf7d1853dfc30c1c44f571d3919eeeedef002823b66b6a988d27e919686389
RUN set -o errexit -o nounset \
    && echo "Installing build dependencies" \
    && apk add --no-cache --virtual .build-deps \
        ca-certificates \
        openssl \
        unzip \
    \
    && echo "Downloading Gradle" \
    && wget -O gradle.zip "https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-${GRADLE_VERSION}-bin.zip" \
    \
    && echo "Checking download hash" \
    && echo "${GRADLE_DOWNLOAD_SHA256} *gradle.zip" | sha256sum -c - \
    \
    && echo "Installing Gradle" \
    && unzip gradle.zip \
    && rm gradle.zip \
    && mkdir /opt \
    && mv "gradle-${GRADLE_VERSION}" "${GRADLE_HOME}/" \
    && ln -s "${GRADLE_HOME}/bin/gradle" /usr/bin/gradle \
    \
    && apk del .build-deps \
    \
    && echo "Adding gradle user and group" \
    && addgroup -S -g 1000 gradle \
    && adduser -D -S -G gradle -u 1000 -s /bin/ash gradle \
    && mkdir /home/gradle/.gradle \
    && chown -R gradle:gradle /home/gradle \
    \
    && echo "Symlinking root Gradle cache to gradle Gradle cache" \
    && ln -s /home/gradle/.gradle /root/.gradle

# Create Gradle volume
USER gradle
VOLUME "/home/gradle/.gradle"
WORKDIR /home/gradle

RUN set -o errexit -o nounset \
    && echo "Testing Gradle installation" \
    && gradle --version
```

EDIT:
Okay how to use gradle in docker after it is downloaded as image and available in gitlab.

```
build_java:
  image: docker:dind
  stage: build_java
  script:
    - docker images
    - docker login -u _json_key -p "$(echo $GCR_SERVICE_ACCOUNT | base64 -d)" https://eu.gcr.io
    - docker pull eu.gcr.io/test/gradle:4.4.1-jdk8-alpine-root
    - docker images
    - ??WHAT COMMAND TO CALL GRADLE BUILD??
```

Comment: The `USER` directive controls which user id is used to run commands. You would need to remove the `USER grade` line from your Dockerfile.

Comment: Can you tell me the command to use gradle after it is downloaded and available as image? Docker run gradle build is not working.

Comment: I am not at all familiar with `gradle`, sorry.

Comment: okay as a workaround I push the image to my dockerhub: https://hub.docker.com/r/tschwalbe/gradle/